# Socket.io 1.1 - How to sent data from client when connecting initially

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I want functionality similar to this

Client

```
var socket=io.connect(url,data);
```

Server

```
io.on('connection',function(socket){
   //get data here in the socket object or in other way
})
```

I know that the data can be obtained by emitting after connecting but I want to know whether there's a way to send data when connecting initially.

Comment: If I'm getting this right, you want to avoid using `socket.emit`? I don't think it's possible to emit data while connecting like that. [The second arguments takes just options](http://socket.io/docs/client-api/#manager%28url:string,-opts:object%29). Out of curiosity, why do you wanna do this?

Comment: I want to get the identity of the user when connecting for storing purposes, I just want to avoid an emit just to give the identity of the user.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best you can do is pass data along with the URL

```
var socket = io.connect(url + "?data=value");
```

Which will be available in `socket.handshake.query` on the server

```
io.on('connection',function(socket){
    var data = socket.handshake.query.data; // => "value"
});
```

---

Or if you're using [passport.socketio](https://github.com/jfromaniello/passport.socketio) you'll have the `socket.request.user` to identify the user.

Comment: Thank you, this works as expected. Will have a look at passport.socketio as well.